# Lstinline macro inside another environment

Tags: macros, listings, verbatim

Why does the MWE below compile with errors only if I use ths `\lstnewenvironment` line? And how to define the verbatim macro inside an environment? I heard it's possible using plain TeX?

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\IfFileExists{randompackageyoudonthave.sty}{
}{
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{Rcode}{\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Rcode}}% deleting this line makes this work
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\lstinline{##1}}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\code{yeah! some code}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were missing the end part of the environment; the syntax (without arguments) is

```
\lstnewenvironment{<name>}{<begin-env>}{<end-env>}
```

Your example code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\IfFileExists{randompackageyoudonthave.sty}{
}{
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{Rcode}{\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Rcode}}{}
\newcommand{\code}{\lstinline}
}

\begin{document}
\code{yeah! some code}

\code+yeah! some code+
\begin{Rcode}
yeah! some code
\end{Rcode}
\end{document}
```

Also, as **egreg** mentioned in [`his comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179606/lstinline-macro-inside-another-environment/179607#comment414791_179607), it should be

```
\newcommand{\code}{\lstinline}
```

or

```
\newcommand{\code}{\lstinline[<options>]}
```

if some `[<options>]` should be used. This allows for the use of alternative delimiters, as in `\code+text+` (see the example code above).

Comment: Also there should be `\newcommand{\code}{\lstinline[<options>]}` ***without*** argument.

Comment: @egreg I've introduced your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: In this way also the alternative syntax `\code!<code>!` (`!` any character like for `\verb`) is allowed, but it's not the only reason.