# Usage of minted inside newenvironment in minted 2.0a³

Tags: environments, verbatim, minted

As a followup question to [Lstinline macro inside another environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179606/lstinline-macro-inside-another-environment), I kind of want to do the same thing for `minted` as well, but I'm held back by the following:

I used the code from [Using minted to define a new environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17458/using-minted-to-define-a-new-environment) but that doesn't seem to work so well for the latest version of `minted` (version 2.0 alpha 3). `\mintinline` works nicely in the latest version. Preferrably I wouldn't want to choose between the two.

Any known workaround to this?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\makeatletter
\IfFileExists{minted.sty}{%
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{euryris}
\usepackage{lineno}
\def\gobble##1{}
\renewcommand\DeleteFile[1]{}
\newenvironment{MyEnvironment}{% works fine in v1.7 ?
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \minted@resetoptions
  \setkeys{minted@opt}{}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}    
      \begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.pyg}}
{%
      \end{VerbatimOut}
      \minted@pygmentize{python}
      \DeleteFile{\jobname.pyg}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{center}}
}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{Environment}
Have some python code:
\begin{MyEnvironment}
print(x**2)
\end{MyEnvironment}
...as the pleasure is all mine.

\section{Inline code}
Some serious inline code right here:~\mintinline{python}{print(x**2)}. Some seriously ugly \jobname.pyg to the right % works fine in v2.0 ?
\end{document}
```

I'm also looking to embed `\mintinline` inside another macro. Not sure if the same recipe as `lstinline` applies?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on what you are doing, you may want to take a look at the `\newminted` and `\newmintinline` macros.  These allow you to create custom versions with your own default arguments.

If you do need to create your own environment containing `minted`, this works and is simpler, since it doesn't get into the `minted` internals:

```
\newenvironment{MyEnvironment}{%
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{center}%
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
      \begin{minted}{python}}
{%
      \end{minted}%
    \end{minipage}%
  \end{center}}
```

The `minipage` and `center` won't necessarily be needed, depending on your final objective.

You should be able to treat `\mintinline` like you would `\lstinline` without any trouble.  Also, in most situations you should be able to treat it just like any other macro, so long as you aren't using the `#` and `%` characters.